# A recursive DFS template to find the shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am learning DFS through [dfs-template I - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/queue-stack/232/practical-application-stack/1384/)

It introduced a recursion template

```
/*
 * Return true if there is a path from cur to target.
 */
boolean DFS(Node cur, Node target, Set<Node> visited) {
    return true if cur is target;
    for (next : each neighbor of cur) {
        if (next is not in visited) {
            add next to visted;
            return true if DFS(next, target, visited) == true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A question raised in the end

> In the template above, we stop when we find the `first` path.
>
> What if you want to find the `shortest` path?
>
> Hint: Add one more parameter to indicate the shortest path you have already found.

How to find the shortest path?

I assumed that a `step` parameter should be added to remember  `depth` of  each turn to traverse, after exhausted all all the possible paths, compare the depths and return the minimal.

Where is the parameter `step`  placed?

Comment: DFS isn't suitable for finding the shortest path in a graph, although it can work in a tree.  To find the shortest path in an unweighted directed or undirected graph, you should use BFS instead.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198910/cant-we-find-shortest-path-by-dfsmodified-dfs-in-an-unweighted-graph-and-if/54199625#54199625

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't we find Shortest Path by DFS(Modified DFS) in an unweighted Graph? and if not then Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198910/cant-we-find-shortest-path-by-dfsmodified-dfs-in-an-unweighted-graph-and-if)

Answer (score 1):

```
distances = new int[numberOfNodes];
boolean DFS(Node cur, Node target, Set<Node> visited, level) {
    for (next : each neighbor of cur) {
        if (next is not in visited and level + 1 < distances[next]) {
            distances[neighbor] = level + 1
            add next to visted;
            DFS(next, target, visited, level + 1)
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the array distances will store shortest path for every node